# How to load / show a UIImageView in cell after cell is populated

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` of images, and in the corner of each cell i have a watermark (*or a small icon*). The images are fetched remotely and the icon is hardcoded (local). Everything is works fine except for one ugly problem: The local watermark icon is loading every cell first, while fetching the images, which is not a good look.
---> I'm looking for a way to load / show the watermark icon (`UIImageView`) after the each cell is populated (*or worse case, after all cells are populated*). Your help is always appreciated!

**1.** Is this possible? **2.** Where would i implement it: `cellForItemAt`, `viewDidLoad`, etc.? **3.** and then what would be the code. Please note i am relatively new to coding.

This is how i populate the collectionView with remotely store image (*listeners not included*):

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "myproductCell", for: indexPath) as! MyProductsCollectionCell
        if (self.products.indices.contains(indexPath.row)) {
            let product = self.products[indexPath.row]
            cell.configureWithProduct(Product(caption: product.caption, videoUrl: product.videoUrl, imageUrl: product.imageUrl))

        }
        return cell
    }
```

And I've just created an outlet for the locally stored watermark (icon):

`@IBOutlet weak var watermark: UIImageView!`

Comment: Show relevant code (as text) in your question. Clearly point out where you need help.

Comment: @rmaddy Thats part of the issue or question, I don't know how and where to implement this, I could post my whole collectionView code but i thought that would be a lot & frown upon here. I guess my question is in 3 parts.   **1.** is what i want possible?  **2.** Where would i implement it, in which function ```cellForItemAt```, ```viewDidLoad```, etc.?  **3.** and then the code. I'll update my question to reflect this. Please note i am relatively new to coding.

Comment: Show just the code you have that is relevant to the image loading which probably includes `cellForItemAt`. Show the code that shows both images.

Comment: Ok @rmaddy I've added my collectionView populating code, hope this helps you help me :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage) library.

First install the library using cocoapods

```swift
pod 'SDWebImage'
```

Import the SDWebImage library above your `MyProductsCollectionCell` and set the image using the method provided by `SDWebImage`.

The library will handle the async downloading, setting of image & caching it.

```swift
import SDWebImage

class MyProductsCollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var watermark: UIImageView!
    // rest of your properties.

    func configureWithProduct(_ product: Product) {
        cell.watermark.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: product.imageUrl), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))
        // set values to the rest properties.
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I haven't seen your code, so I can't comment. But definitely **not in viewDidLoad.**

You could use blocks to implement this in cellForItemAt.

```
- (__kindof UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // download the image on the background thread
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        // once you have the image downloaded, 
        // set the image on a main thread
        // in the completion handler
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue, ^{
            callback(yourImage); // this can be a call to your method.
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: The question is tagged Swift. Please post answers in the proper language.

Comment: What is completionHandler?

Comment: @barryjones thanks for your response, I've added my ```cellForItemAt``` code to the question, please have another look.

Comment: @Jamakes In this method, cell.configureWithProduct you should download the image and then set the image on the main thread, similar to the dispatch method, I have used in my description.

Comment: URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: imageUrl!) { data, _, error in
    if error != nil {
        print(error)
        return
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        imageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)
    }
}.resume()

Comment: To be honest @barryjones networking (caching, storage, etc.) is the part I'm soo unsure about and could do with some real help. Are you a gun for hire? or can you be? lol. Just a couple of hours to review my network implementation and talk me through it. That would be so awesome! let me know, Jamakes.

Comment: @jamakes what are you having difficulty in ?

Comment: Hey @barryjones sorry was travelling. Well everything lol, it's like learning Japanese in months and then having to write a book in Japanese using different translation dictionaries, some of which contradict each other lol, I'm just never 100% sure of what i'm doing is good practice. :)

Comment: @barryjones So, below is the urlsession code, can you kindly tell me where and what I should place to achieve the "*Show uiImageView in cell after loading cell data*:

Comment: ```
    func getData(from url: URL, completion: @escaping (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> ()) {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: completion).resume()
    }
    func downloadImage(from url: URL, imageView: UIImageView) {
        print("Download Started")
        let urlString = url.absoluteString
        if let cachedVersion = ProductImagePlayer.imageCache.object(forKey: urlString as NSString) {
            print("PRODUCT: image from cache for \(url.absoluteString)")
            imageView.image = cachedVersion.image
            return
        }...

Comment: ...let ref = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: urlString)
        ref.getData(maxSize: 2 * 1024 * 1024, completion: {(data, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("PRODUCT: blah, blah, -> \(url.absoluteString)")
            } else {
                if let imgData = data {
                    if let img = UIImage(data: imgData) {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                            print("PRODUCT: image downloaded from firebase \(url.absoluteString)")
                            imageView.image = img
                        }...